# keep checkbox checked onchange() event in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have tried a lot and did a lot of googling to keep the checkbox checked onchange event in javascript but I am not being able to do it. The value of the checkbox is getting stored in localStorage but the checkbox doesn't remain active. Kindly help I have tried a lot below is the code for your perusal.
Below is my HTML Code:

```
<html>
<body>
 <label class="switch" data-toggle="tooltip" title="click to change theme" data-placement="left">
            <input type="checkbox" id="toggleme" name="toggleme" onchange="changeTheme()"> <span class="slider round"></span> </label>
 <div id="changeColor">

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my JS Code:

```
<script>
    function changeTheme() {
        var toggleSwitch = document.getElementById('toggleme'),
            toggleButton;
        var divColor = document.getElementById('changeColor');
        var heading = document.getElementById('sub-heading');
        var td = document.getElementById('td-color');
        var td_1 = document.getElementById('td-color-1');
        var td_2 = document.getElementById('td-color-2');
        var td_3 = document.getElementById('td-color-3');
        var td_4 = document.getElementById('td-color-4');
        localStorage.setItem('toggleButton', toggleSwitch.checked);
        if (toggleSwitch.checked) {
            var checked = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('toggleButton'));
            document.getElementById('toggleme').checked = true;
            divColor.style.backgroundColor = '#2e2e2e';
            heading.style.color = '#fff';
            td.style.color = '#fff';
            td_1.style.color = '#fff';
            td_2.style.color = '#fff';
            td_3.style.color = '#fff';
            td_3.style.color = '#fff';
            td_4.style.color = '#fff';
        } else {
            localStorage.removeItem('toggleButton');
            divColor.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
            heading.style.color = '#000';
            td.style.color = '#2e2e2e';
            td_1.style.color = '#2e2e2e';
            td_2.style.color = '#2e2e2e';
            td_3.style.color = '#2e2e2e';
            td_4.style.color = '#2e2e2e';
        }
    };

    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('toggleme').checked = localStorage.checked;
        var divColor = document.getElementById('changeColor');
        divColor.style.backgroundColor = '#2e2e2e';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: And where is the code, which should load the state from the local storage?

Comment: I didn't got your point are you asking me  about the localStorage.getItem method actually this is the first time I am using localStorage object

Comment: @Philipp are you there?

Comment: You should post the entire code HTML + JS

Comment: I have posted kindly have a look at the HTML code